# Optimize query to get rows with highest, filtered count in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to create the most optimal query where the database would return the names of readers who often borrow sci-fi books. That's what I'm trying to optimize:

```
SELECT reader.name, 
COUNT (CASE WHEN book.status_id = 1 AND book.category_id = 2 THEN 1 END)
FROM reader
JOIN book ON book.reader_id = reader.id
GROUP BY reader.name
ORDER BY COUNT (CASE WHEN book.status_id = 1 AND book.category_id = 2 THEN 1 END) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

How can I improve my query other than with `INNER JOIN` or memory consumption increase?

This is my ERD diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could try to add your criteria in your join statement and just use the total count. It really depends on how much data you have etc....

```
SELECT reader.name, 
COUNT(1) AS COUNTER
FROM reader
JOIN book ON book.reader_id = reader.id
AND book.status_id = 1
AND book.category = 2
GROUP BY reader.name
ORDER BY COUNTER DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming at least 10 readers that pass the criteria (like another answer also silently assumes), else you get fewer than 10 result rows.

Start with the filter. Aggregate & limit *before* joining to the second table. Much cheaper:

```sql
SELECT r.reader_id, r.surname, r.name, b.ct
FROM  (
   SELECT reader_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   book
   WHERE  status_id = 1
   AND    category_id = 2
   GROUP  BY reader_id
   ORDER  BY ct DESC, reader_id  -- tiebreaker
   LIMIT  10
   ) b
JOIN   reader r ON r.id = b.reader_id
ORDER  BY b.ct DESC, r.reader_id;  -- tiebreaker
```

A multicolumn **index** on `(status_id, category_id)` would help a lot. Or an index on just one of both columns if either predicate is very selective. If performance of this particular query is your paramount objective, have this [partial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) multicolumn index:

```
CREATE INDEX book_reader_special_idx ON book (reader_id)
WHERE status_id = 1 AND category_id = 2;
```

Typically, you'd vary the query, then this last index is too specialized.

Additional points:

- Group by `reader_id`, which is the primary key (I assume) and guaranteed to be unique - as opposed to `reader.name`! Your original is likely to fail completely, `name` being just the "first name" from the looks of your ERD.
  It's also typically substantially faster to group by an `integer` instead of `varchar(25)` (two times). But that's secondary, correctness comes first.
- Also output `surname` and `reader_id` to disambiguate identical names. (Even name & surname are not reliably unique.)
- `count(*)` is faster than `count(1)` while doing the same, exactly.
- Add a tiebreaker to the `ORDER BY` clause to get a stable sort order and deterministic results. (Else, the result can be different every time with ties on the count.)